# tableView.reloadData() does not refresh table until scrolled, even with dispatch_async

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, swift

I'm having a rather common issue, but the solutions so far have not given me the desired result.

I have a `UITableView` that I am populating with information that I have parsed from a JSON pulled from the web at run time. The JSON retrieval starts in `func viewDidLoad()` using the `NSURLSession.dataTaskWithURL(NSURL, completionHandler)` function. The cells of the table are then populated within the `completionHandler`.

The cells used in the table are custom, and all UI elements in the cell have default values set through the interface builder.

When the table appears it is completely empty, though it does have the proper cell height. The reason I found for this behavior is that the `reloadData` function isn't being called at the right time due to multithreading/multiprocessing and the suggested solution is to have

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
    self.tableView.reloadData()
})
```

somewhere in the code to allow the reload to occur correctly. However, this only partially works. The table flickers with what looks like content, and then immediately goes blank again until I scroll. Once I scroll the `reloadData` function works as expected, but only after I scroll.

I've tried having the `reloadData` function in various locations (such as in `viewWillAppear`) with no luck. Are there any ideas or troubleshooting tips that I can try?

**Edit #1 - Request for completion handler**

```
var listTask = session.dataTaskWithURL(listUrl, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
    if error == nil {
        var json:NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .MutableContainers, error: nil) as NSDictionary
        var topGames = json["top"] as [NSDictionary]
        var currGame:NSDictionary
        var toAdd:Game
        for var i=0; i < topGames.count; ++i {
            currGame = topGames[i]["game"] as NSDictionary
            toAdd = Game(
                id: String(currGame["_id"] as CLong),
                name: currGame["name"] as NSString,
                boxArtImageUrl: (currGame["box"] as NSDictionary)["medium"] as NSString,
                boxArtImage: nil,
                isFetchingBoxArt: false,
                totalViewers: topGames[i]["viewers"] as Int,
                totalChannels: topGames[i]["channels"] as Int,
                topChannel: "N/A")
            self.games.append(toAdd)
        }
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        })
    }
}
```

Note that the self.games array is used in `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCel` to fill in the information in the cells.

**Edit #2 - Request for `cellForRowAtIndexPath`**

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell:TopGameListCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("topGameCell") as TopGameListCell
    if games.count > 0 {
        var game:Game = games[indexPath.row]
        cell.nameLabel?.text = game.name
        cell.totalViewersLabel.text = String(game.totalViewers)
        cell.totalChannelsLabel.text = String(game.totalChannels)
        cell.topChannelLabel.text = game.topChannel
        if game.boxArtImage != nil {
            cell.boxArtImageView.image = game.boxArtImage
        } else {
            if(!game.isFetchingBoxArt) {
                cell.boxArtImageView.image = placeholderImage
                gatherGameBoxArtImageForCell(game.boxArtImageUrl, indexPath: indexPath)
            }
        }
    }
    return cell;
}
```

I forgot about the extra fetch that I start within the `gatherGameBoxArtImageForCell`. Basically if I don't already have the image, download it. The if/else for the image seems to be causing the flicker to occur. If I let it sit long enough, it finally shows the table. The idea for me is that the placeholder image would show until the image is downloaded, and then `reloadData` is called after the image is downloaded. Here is the image fetch `completionHandler`:

```
var task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
    var game = self.games[indexPath.row]
    if error == nil {
        if(game.boxArtImage == nil) {
            var cellForImage:TopGameListCell? = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? TopGameListCell
            if cellForImage != nil {
                self.games[indexPath.row].boxArtImage = UIImage(data: data)
                cellForImage?.boxArtImageView.image = self.games[indexPath.row].boxArtImage
            }
        }
    } else {
        println(error)
    }
    game.isFetchingBoxArt = false
    self.tableView.reloadData()
})
```

Comment: did you try the above block code in your completion handler? Since you are updating the data holder in parallel, you can check by making the data holder atomic.  [Do you reload the table on scroll]?

Comment: Thanks for your comment Naveen! I have tried having the above block immediately after all data is gathered, but with no luck. The table still stays blank. The scrolling behavior is all default; I haven't altered the code in an way for the scrolling.

Comment: can you show where you are reloading the tableview inside the completion block?

Comment: also can you please show your cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

Comment: Updated, but it now seems to be working. No idea what happened or what is different than before.

Comment: Wait! Nevermind, it's borking again. About to update with some info.

Comment: I notice that you pass your cell instance to `gatherGameBoxArtImageForCell` - This can be risky as the cell may have been reused by the time the image is received.   Can you show this method

Comment: Added that function as you posted it, Paulw11. :) Well most of it. The first two lines are just the session setup. The meat is in the completionHandler, which is now in the OP.

Comment: Looking at it again, it seems that cell being passed in is actually extra and not needed.

Comment: Are you sure the JSON is being parsed correctly? Did by any chance you forgot to call `listTask.resume()`?

Comment: The OP code now reflects some edits I made but still have the same problem. The cell is no longer passed into `gatherGameBoxArtImageForCell`. I'll change the function name later. :) @OscarSwanros: `listTask.resume()` is indeed being called. The data is correctly parsed as the image does show up on scroll, or when I wait for awhile.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that when I was trying to have the images load in the background it was hogging up the main thread. What I did was changed the following from

```
if(!game.isFetchingBoxArt) {
    cell.boxArtImageView.image = placeholderImage
    gatherGameBoxArtImageForCell(game.boxArtImageUrl, indexPath: indexPath)
}
```

to

```
if(!game.isFetchingBoxArt) {
    cell.boxArtImageView.image = placeholderImage
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        self.gatherGameBoxArtImageForCell(game.boxArtImageUrl, indexPath: indexPath)
    })
}
```

I decided to do this after thinking on how the normal solution is to place `reloadData` in a `dispatch_async`. Apparently the reasoning is the same for the issue I was having, so now the download of the images runs asynchronously.